# Where can i find kafka message headers in the Landoop kafka UI?

Tags: apache-kafka, header

I am trying to publish some messages along with few custom headers, to kafka. But I am not able to see those header details in the Landoop Kafka UI. Could someone let me know where the header section is present in the kafka Landoop UI ?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available in Lenses product (developed by same people as Kafka Topics UI) that you can access from lenses.io. This explains how you can do it: https://help.lenses.io/knowledge-base/sql/how-to-view-kafka-message-headers/